# X11 from ssh on Mac OSX to Linux server doesn't work --- Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display

Tags: linux, mac-osx, x11, x11forwarding, gtk

I installed a program wireshark on my remote linux box and I'm trying to run it with X11 from my mac computer using SSH.
Here's my terminal...

```
macosx$ echo $DISPLAY
/tmp/launch-f4w6k6/:0

macosx$ ssh -X root@myserver.com
root@myserver.com's password: 

remoteubuntu:~# echo $DISPLAY

remoteubuntu:~# wireshark

(wireshark:18927): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

Here's a few lines from /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [-Y option](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh) for X11 forwarding instead it disables some X11 security checks and tends to work better from OSX.

Comment: In addition to trying `-Y`, also make sure that your remote system has the `xauth` binary available: ssh **requires** that binary in order to successfully set up forwarding.

Comment: Actually... the only thing I had to do was install xauth. It works with or without the -Y option now. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

X11 is not installed in MacOS X Lion. MacOS X Lion users have to install XQuartz for ssh -X or -Y to work.

For reference: [About X11 and OS X Mountain Lion](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5293)

Comment: +1 This was the only resource that I could find anywhere that mentioned this, and it was **exactly** what I needed to solve my problem.  When I tried `ssh -X -v` on my system, `xauth` did not appear ANYWHERE in the output....  Then I installed XQuartz.  One logout/login later, and it all Just Works.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an X server running on your local system. Don't use Terminal.app(the one with a black icon) to start your SSH session; instead, use X11.app(the one with a white icon). On my system, it's in /Applications/Utilities/X11.app.

Comment: If you do ssh -X from the Terminal, it will automatically launch X11.app

Answer (score 0):

Xnest -geometry 1024x768 :1& DISPLAY=:1 ssh -Y ipoftheserver gnome-session
work well !

Answer (score 0):

Another important thing: if you install `xquartz` via `homebrew`, **you should relogin your macos or reboot.**

As the [rackpas's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1430166/851459) saying.